# Hidden-md-down is not working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to hide a modal from appearing for mobile and tablets.

In bootstrap, I am using hidden-md-down and it was working but it isnt working anymore and I haven't change anything:

```js
$(function(){
  $('##myModal').modal('show');
});
```

```html
<div class="ie-only" style="overflow-y:hidden;">
         <div class="modal fade in hidden-md-down" id="myModal" aria-hidden="false">
             <div class="modal-dialog modal-md custom-height-modal">
                 <div class="modal-content">
                              <div class="modal-header topGrad" 
                         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
                            <h2 class="modal-header" style=""filter: alpha(opacity=200);">Outdated Browser Detected</h2><p>Our website has detected that you are using an outdated browser. Using your current browser will prevent you from accesing featuers on your website. An upgrade is not required, but is strongly recommend to improve your browsing experince on our website.<br /><br />
                            <b>Use the links below to download a new browser or upgrade your existing browser.</b></p> 
                        </div><!---Modal-Header Div--->
                        <div class="modal-body">
                         <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-2 overrides-col-md-offset-2 col-md-2 text-center">
                                    <div class="hidden-xs"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html"><img alt="Chrome" height="200px" src="/default/images/chrome.png" width="440px" /></a></div>
                        
                                    <h6><a class="text-black" target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html">Chrome</a></h6>
                                </div>
                        
                                <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 text-center">
                                    <div class="hidden-xs"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/?f=86"><img alt="Firefox" src="/default/images/firefox.png" /></a></div>
                        
                                    <h6><a class="text-black" target="_blank" href="https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/?f=86">Firefox</a></h6>
                                </div>
                        
                                <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 text-center">
                                    <div class="hidden-xs"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/internet-explorer.aspx"><img alt="Internet Explorer" src="/default/images/internet_explorer.png" /></a></div>
                        
                                    <h6><a target="_blank" class="text-black" href="https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/internet-explorer.aspx">Internet Explorer</a></h6>
                                </div>
                        
                                <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 text-center">
                                    <div class="hidden-xs"><a target="_blank" href="https://support.apple.com/downloads/safari"><img alt="Safari" src="/default/images/safari.png" /></a></div>
                        
                                    <h6><a class="text-black" target="_blank" href="https://support.apple.com/downloads/safari">Safari</a></h6>
                                </div>
       </div>
                        </div><!---Modal-Body Div--->
                        <div class="modal-footer botGrad" <!---style="background-image:('/mura-6.2.6407/Regal-en-us/images/extended_bottom_provider.gif');"---> style="background-color:##4f89cc;  filter: alpha(opacity=80);">
                         <p class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" style="filter: alpha(opacity=100);">Close</a></p>
                        </div><!---Modal-Footer Div--->
                    </div><!---Modal-Content Div--->
                </div><!---Custom Height Div--->
            </div><!---Modal Fade in Div--->
        </div><!---Start of Modal Div--->     
  <!--End of Modal container-->
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `$('##myModal')` typo here. Use single `#`

Comment: @user2181397 Sorry I am in coldfusion and if I use single #, it will crash. Sorry for not adding that piece of info

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap 4?

Comment: @Skelly: Bootstrap v3.3.6 and it was working fine but for some reason it stopped

Answer (score 1):

In [Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) the classes are `hidden-md`, `hidden-sm`, `hidden-xs`, etc..

The `hidden-md-down` class only exists in Bootstrap 4.

Comment: If I would update Bootstrap I am currently using to Bootstrap 4, would effect any changes  I currently have or does Bootstrap 4 have all the classes that the previous version that I am using?

Comment: Bootstrap 4 has only been released in alpha, and the classes are different than Bootstrap 3. Its not intended to be backwards compatible.

Comment: I was able to use it without going to 4, I just erased and uploaded the same bootstrap file and now it works again