# How can I register to Bootstrapper on Navbar changed event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a small homepage. Depending on the `Navbar` style (with or without hamburger menu) I want to display the `span` with `id=actualPage`. How can I achieve that (JQuery, JavaScript or even with CSS)? - I read a lot about collapse etc but I am not sure if this is the right approach and I have not found any easy solution.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand active" href="index.php?p=home">MyPage
                <span id="actualPage">- <?= $pages[$activePage] ?></span></a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                ...
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the given problem, by using the `hidden` classes. - It does not actually solve the question but the origin problem.

In Bootstrap 3:

```
<a class="navbar-brand active">Test<span id="actualPage" class="hidden-xl hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm">- <?= $pages[$activePage] ?></span></a>
```

In Bootstrap 4:

```
<a class="navbar-brand active">Test<span id="actualPage" class="hidden-sm-up">- <?= $pages[$activePage] ?></span></a>
```

Check the following link: [Hidden-md-down is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38728049/hidden-md-down-is-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

Well, if memory serves, Bootstraps Nav collapses to a hamburger at 1200px.

If all you want is for the span to only be visible when uncollapsed just use css with something like:

```
.mySpan{ display: inline-block;}
@media (min-width: 1200px) { .mySpan{display: none;}}
```

If you need that ID for some kind of computation and want to to not EXIST then you'd have to use JS to add / remove the ID based on the screen being <1200px

EDIT:
For a JS solution it would be something like:

```
window.onresize = function() {
    if (window.innerwidth<1200px){
        document.getElementById("small").id = "big";
    }
    else{
        document.getElementByID("big").id = "small";
    }
};
```

Comment: how could I add a callback to the navbar change?

Comment: it wouldnt have to be related to the navbar change. The navbar changes at 1200px wide. You're just copying it's behaviour. are you asking about the JS option? to add / remove the id based on screen width?

Comment: how can i attach some kind of callback to the navbar change in javascript?

Comment: Thank you very much for your adivce, I solved it a little bit different, check my answer.